# Flutter-Overflow happends if i addded many items in a chip even after wrapping it with Wrap widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am having an issue related to Chip and Wrap widgets. I am trying to wrap the chips within a wrap widget but eve does not do any, it gives me an overflow error, despite that I did it in another place and it was working. I tried using stack but did not work, also I read the docs but did not solve it.
This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mar/exports/screens.dart'
    show DeliveryOfferCreationScreen, DeliveryOfferScreen, MyOrderScreen;
import 'package:mar/exports/utils.dart';
import 'package:mar/localization/app_locale.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = "home_screen";
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  // values
  List texts = ['hhhhhh', 'gggggggg', 'fffffffff', 'rrrrrrrrr', 'eeeeeeee'];

  // methods

  /* Widget chip(String text) {
    return Chip(
      label: Center(
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
      labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.5),
      backgroundColor: kYellow,
    );
  } */

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 220,
                  width: size.width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.25),
                        offset: Offset(0, 6),
                        blurRadius: 12,
                        spreadRadius: 4,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: size.width,
                        height: 40,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Close At 10:30',
                            style: kTextStyleH3.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Image(
                            image: AssetImage(
                              //'assets/resImages/mc.png',
                            ),
                            height: 100,
                            width: 100,
                          ),
                          Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                child: Wrap(
                                  spacing: 2,
                                  runSpacing: 2,
                                  children: texts.map((text) {
                                    return Chip(
                                      label: Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          text,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      materialTapTargetSize:
                                          MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                                      labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.5),
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                                    );
                                  }).toList(),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: size.width,
                        height: 40,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '6',
                            style: kTextStyleH3.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is what I have,
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOfjK.png): [image]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap label: Text('chip') in Container or SizedBox or you can use an expanded widget or a list like this

```
final List<String> tags = ['HHHHHHHHH', 'KKKKKKKKK', 'KKKKLLLLL', 'JJJJJJJJJ', 'MMMMMMMMM', 'DDDDDDDDD']

Wrap(
      children: tags.map((tag) {
         return Container(
       margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
   child: Chip(
      label: Text(tag)
    ),
  );
 }).toList(),
)
```

Comment: does not work!!. do you mean i should add it in the chip method ?

Comment: I have edited my answer can you check the above solution now.

Comment: it did not work. I updated my question to see the design that I want.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63604015/getting-overflowed-error-on-dynamic-chips-in-flutter)[ check this thread once ]

Comment: it did not work, it keeps throwing exception 'size.content >= boxSize.height' :( . also i update my code.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Wrap` widget with `SingleChildScrollView` and give `scrollDirection` to `Axis.horizontal`

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Wrap(
        spacing: 2,
        runSpacing: 2,
        children: tags.map((tag) {
          return Chip(label: Text(tag));
        }).toList(),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: it did work also :(.

Comment: @S.A. don't forget to mark it as clarified if it is worked for you.